# removing near duplicate objects in Python list

Tags: python, comparison-operators

I want to compare objects and declare them equal if they are close.

Here I have a class `Person` which has attributes `name`, `age`, and `sex`. I would like two people to be determined to be the same person if they have the same name and their ages are within tolerance of each other, independent of gender.

I had hoped to do this as below but this doesn't work because objects that declare equal have to have the same hash value.

In the example below I would like set(People) to return only a single person because I am not comparing `sex` and they all have the same name and their ages are equal to within tol.

Is there a clean way to fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

tol=5

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex):
            self.name = name
            self.age  = age
            self.sex  = sex
    def __repr__(self):
            return repr((self.name, self.age, self.sex))

    def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.name==other.name and (abs(self.age-other.age)<tol)

    def __hash__(self):
            return hash((self.name,self.age))     

names=["James Jones", "James Jones", "James Jones"]
ages = [47.53,47.53,47.531]
sexes=["M","F","M"]
People=[]

for i in range(3):
    People.append(Person(names[i],ages[i],sexes[i]))

for person in set(People):
    print person
```

Comment: You shouldn't define equality in terms of numerical closeness, because it is not transitive. If you have similarly named people of age 11, 14 and 17, then the first two would be "equal", and the last two are "equal", but the first and last are not "equal". So which one(s) do you expect to be retained?

Comment: You can remove `self.age` from your `__hash__` function, but you'll still have the same problem as @khelwood said

Comment: OK. So compute the mean age of all the people with the same name and count all who are within tol of the mean to be the same person. I guess there isn't a clean way to do this within this framework?

Comment: But that doesn't work because I am looking for clusters. I guess I can define a cluster size and then find all the people with the same name that are within cluster size of each other compute the mean age and define the mean person for the cluster and keep that one. I guess I should simply construct a new list based on these criteria?

Comment: Of course, clusters need not be transitive either but that simply doesn't matter. The data are clustered. I am trying to count the number of clusters with the same name. If I have five people in one cluster and three in another, I want to end up with two people, which could be the mean person of each of the two clusters, or it could just be a representative person from each of the two clusters.

Comment: ChatterOne, thanks for your comment. Removing self.age is what I needed.  I would vote that up as an answer. I understand the logic of khelwood's concern but it simply isn't that big an issue for me.   I am trying to count the distinct uses of words in place names in gis files. If Jones Mountain, Jones Creek, and Jones Canyon are all within a short distance of each other, I count them as a single use of "Jones" because, more likely than not, they're all named for the same "Jones". khelwood's comment makes the perfect the enemy of the good enough.

Comment: @user1688949 I wasn't saying "here is an insurmountable problem with your goal", I was asking "In this situation, what outcome are you expecting?" Answering that question (figuring out specifically what you are aiming for) is part of getting a solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the `__eq__()` method that will do comparisons you will also have to implement a `__hash__()` method that would return the same value for objects that should be considered the same. This might be hard with your date threshold.